# Converting Chess FEN Notation to a Tuple and Back

Tags: strings, chess, elixir

This module is going to be part of a larger [`ElixirChess`](https://github.com/shiftyp/elixirchess) library for validating chess positions and moves, but I started with the core of it which is parsing a position from FEN notation into a more consumable format and back again. I'm basing this somewhat on [Chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/chess.js), so I decided to convert the board to a tuple of pairs where each pair has an atom for the piece and one for the color. You can see the examples in the function docs below.

It works and the doctests pass, but this is the first large piece of code I've written in Elixir and I'm interested to see if I'm following best practices or if there's some pattern I can improve upon. I'm particularly interested if there's a better way to recurse in both the parsing and serialization steps since the functional way of doing things is a little new to me. Thanks.

Oh, and not included is the full module Constants since I'm only using one method on it here, but I'll post the relevant snippet below the Board module.

```
defmodule Board do
  alias Constants, as: C

  @moduledoc """
  Board contains methods for parsing fen postions and serializing board tuples
  """

  @doc """
  The parsePosition function takes a position from a fen string and converts it
  into a tuple where each item is a tuple which represents the piece and color
  occupying the square. It is the inverse of serializeBoard. For example:

  iex> Board.parsePosition("rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R")
  {
    {:r, :b}, {:n, :b}, {:b, :b}, {:q, :b}, {:k, :b}, {:b, :b}, {:n, :b}, {:r, :b},
    {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b},
    {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
    {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :b}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
    {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
    {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:n, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
    {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w},
    {:r, :w}, {:n, :w}, {:b, :w}, {:q, :w}, {:k, :w}, {:b, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:r, :w}
  }
  """
  @spec parsePosition(binary) :: tuple

  def parsePosition(position) do
    # We convert the string to a char list, then we create a list from it.
    # Ultimately we want a touple since the size of a chess board is fixed, and
    # we'll want to access it by index.
    position
      |> String.codepoints()
      |> createSquares()
      |> List.to_tuple()
  end

  @spec createSquares(list) :: list

  defp createSquares([piece | rest]) do
    # Get the square, nil for non-square characters
    square = pieceToSquare(piece)
    cond do
      # We've reached the end after an empty square
      rest == [] and square == nil -> []
      # We've reached the end with a non-empty square
      rest == [] -> [square]
      # If the square is empty, add it and process the next square by
      # decrementing the empty counter
      square == {:e, :e} ->
        newPiece = piece
          |> String.to_integer()
          |> - 1
          |> Integer.to_string()
        [square | createSquares([newPiece | rest])]
      # If we have a non-nil square (i.e. a piece)
      square != nil -> [ square | createSquares(rest)]
      # Otherwise we've hit a slash or the end of an empty sequence, so skip.
      true -> createSquares(rest)
    end
  end

  @spec pieceToSquare(binary) :: tuple

  # Non-square characters are nil.
  defp pieceToSquare(piece) when piece == "/" or piece == "0" do
    nil
  end

  # Empty squares are indicated by a counter (still a string).
  defp pieceToSquare(piece) when piece < "9" do
    {:e, :e}
  end

  # Pieces are indicated by their letter, with uppercase indicating white and
  # lowercase indicating black.
  defp pieceToSquare(piece) do
    case piece do
      "p" -> {:p, :b}
      "P" -> {:p, :w}
      "n" -> {:n, :b}
      "N" -> {:n, :w}
      "b" -> {:b, :b}
      "B" -> {:b, :w}
      "r" -> {:r, :b}
      "R" -> {:r, :w}
      "k" -> {:k, :b}
      "K" -> {:k, :w}
      "q" -> {:q, :b}
      "Q" -> {:q, :w}
    end
  end

  @doc """
  The serializeBoard function takes a board (the tuple returned from create board)
  and returns a position suitible for putting in a fen string. It is the inverse
  of parsePosition. For example:

  iex> Board.serializeBoard({
  ...>  {:r, :b}, {:n, :b}, {:b, :b}, {:q, :b}, {:k, :b}, {:b, :b}, {:n, :b}, {:r, :b},
  ...>  {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b}, {:p, :b},
  ...>  {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
  ...>  {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :b}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
  ...>  {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
  ...>  {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e}, {:n, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:e, :e},
  ...>  {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w}, {:p, :w},
  ...>  {:r, :w}, {:n, :w}, {:b, :w}, {:q, :w}, {:k, :w}, {:b, :w}, {:e, :e}, {:r, :w}
  ...> })
  "rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R"
  """

  @spec serializeBoard(tuple) :: binary

  def serializeBoard(board) do
    # We convert the board from a tuple since we'll be looking at the first elem.
    # We start off at index 0 with an empty string and an empty accumulator. We
    # actually build the symbol list by prepending the symbols, then reverse it
    # at the end for performance reasons.
    board
      |> Tuple.to_list()
      |> serializeSquares(0, "", [])
      |> Enum.reverse()
      |> List.to_string
  end

  # The arguments are the remaning squares as a list, an index in the sequence,
  # a string representing the last proccessed symbol, and a list representing the
  # accumulated symbols going into the final string.In the end we return that list.
  # The current symbol isn't appended to the list until the next function call,
  # except in the case where we are at the end of the list of squares. This is to
  # account for empty squares being represented by a single symbol, so it's a
  # reduce operation as opposed to a straight map.
  @spec serializeSquares(list, integer, binary, list) :: list

  # This is the end of a row case, where we want to add a "/" to the list. Note
  # That this will only match in between the rows, and not at the beginning or
  # end of the sequence.
  defp serializeSquares([square | rest], index, prev, acc) when rem(index, 8) == 0 and index > 0 do
    # We pass an empty string as prev just like at the start of the process.
    new = serializeSquare square, ""
    # We don't treat the slash as a symbol, so we don't pass it to the next call.
    serializeSquares(rest, index + 1, new, [[prev, "/"] | acc])
  end

  defp serializeSquares([square | rest], index, prev, acc) do
    new = serializeSquare square, prev
    cond do
      # If we're at the end of the list, finish it up.
      rest == [] -> [[prev, new] | acc]
      # If the previous and current square are both empty.
      prev < "9" and prev > "0" and new < "9" ->
        serializeSquares(rest, index + 1, new, acc)
      # Otherwise we prepend the previous to the accumulator and move on to the
      # next call.
      true ->
        serializeSquares(rest, index + 1, new, [prev | acc])
    end
  end

  @spec serializeSquare(tuple, binary) :: binary

  defp serializeSquare({:e, :e}, prev) do
    # For empty squares, we return a "1" if the prev square was non-empty,
    # Otherwise it was empty and we increment that number.
    if prev == "" or prev > "8" do
      "1"
    else
      prev
        |> String.to_integer()
        |> + 1
        |> Integer.to_string()
    end
  end

  defp serializeSquare({piece, color}, _) do
     C.symbols[color][piece]
  end
end
```

And the snippet from Constants:

```
defmodule Constants do
...
  def symbols do
    [
      b: [p: "p", n: "n", b: "b", r: "r", q: "q", k: "k"],
      w: [p: "P", n: "N", b: "B", r: "R", q: "Q", k: "K"]
    ]
  end
...
end
```

Comment: I actually just noticed an issue when the last row ends in empty squares. Should I edit the question and fix it or leave the code as is? I'm not sure what the etiquette is on codereview.